# Saving an custom object array that is appended constantly

Tags: arrays, swift, save

I'm relatively new to Swift and coding in general. I'm trying to hone my skills at the moment but putting together a simple reminder app. I'm trying to get the back end working before I put together the story board but I have the essential story board elements to test if my system will work.

Basically I'm trying to save a array that contains a custom object, but this array is appended to each reminder addition done by the user. This is so that every time the app opens, the array will contain the reminders from last time.

Here is the code I have so far to create and append the list;

```
func createReminder() {
    let reminderAdd = Reminder(chosenReminderDescription: textRetrieve.text!, chosenReminderLength: 1)
    reminderList.append(reminderAdd)

    dump(reminderList)
}
```

Here is the object code;

```
class Reminder {

    var reminderDescription = "Require initalisation."
    var reminderLength = 1 // in days

    init (chosenReminderDescription: String, chosenReminderLength: Int) {
        reminderDescription = chosenReminderDescription
        reminderLength = chosenReminderLength
    }

}
```

How would I go about saving the array?

**EDIT:** 
This is what i've added so far.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let reminderAdd = Reminder(chosenReminderDescription: "Placeholder test", chosenReminderLength: 1)
    reminderList.append(reminderAdd)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Tasks", in: context)
    let newTask = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

    newTask.setValue(reminderList, forKey: "taskName")

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Failed saving")
    }

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Tasks")
    //request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "age = %@", "12")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            print(data.value(forKey: "taskName"))
        }

    } catch {

        print("Failed")
    }
```

I'm getting crashes and I can't seem to debug it as of yet. I believe this line is causing the crash as when I remove it the app launches fine.

```
let reminderAdd = Reminder(chosenReminderDescription: "Placeholder test", chosenReminderLength: 1)
    reminderList.append(reminderAdd)
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT 2:**
[datamodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wyxY.png)

That is the data model, I'm not entirely sure what you mean to make the object into a codable. Thanks again.

**EDIT 3:**

ViewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Tasks", in: context)
    let newTask = Tasks(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

    newTask.setValue(reminderList, forKey: "taskName")

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Failed saving")
    }

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Tasks")

    //request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "age = %@", "12")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        for data in result as! [Tasks] {
            print(data.value(forKey: "taskName"))

        }

    } catch {

        print("Failed")
    }

    dump(reminderList)
}
```

Comment: You could save this to a `.json` file, a `sqlite` database, `NSUserDefaults`, send it off to a cloud somewhere, or many other persistence alternatives. What have you tried?

Comment: @Ian Don’t use UserDefaults to store app data.

Comment: @rmaddy I mean, I said _could_, not _should_, right? :)

Comment: @IanMacDonald I messed around with the UserDefaults but couldn't get it to work. I'll have a play around tonight and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I've mucked around with the core data but I'm just came to some more problems. I believe the data is saving and fetching, but now that I have tried to add a value to the array so it can actually save something that isn't just an empty array, it crashes, please refer to my edit. Thanks, Sav.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could create an instance using CoreData and store it like an internal database.
These are some good tutorial to start with that:

https://medium.com/xcblog/core-data-with-swift-4-for-beginners-1fc067cca707

https://www.raywenderlich.com/7569-getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial

**EDIT 2**

As you can see in this image,
https://ibb.co/f1axcA
my list in coreData is of type [Notifica], so is an array of object Notifica, to implement codable you should do something like this

```
public class Notifica: NSObject, NSCoding {

public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "id") as? Double
    self.type = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "type") as? String
    self.idEvent = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "idEvent") as? Int
    self.contactPerson = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "contactPerson") as? People
    self.title = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as? String
    self.date = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "date") as? String
}

public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(id, forKey: "id")
    aCoder.encode(type, forKey: "type")
    aCoder.encode(idEvent, forKey: "idEvent")
    aCoder.encode(contactPerson, forKey: "contactPerson")
    aCoder.encode(title, forKey: "title")
    aCoder.encode(date, forKey: "date")
}

ecc..
```

Another thing is to not call NSManagedObject and pass the entity, but you should name that Tasks as you called in dataModel, if you type Tasks on xcode it will fin for you the NSManagedObject created and then you can set the value for taskName

**EDIT 3**

"`<Simple_Reminders.Reminder: 0x60400046da40>`" means that a Reminder object exist! So you saved it! Reminder has two variable: 
-reminderDescription and
-reminderLength, so change your code

```
do {
    let result = try context.fetch(request)
    for data in result as! [Tasks] {
        print(data.value(forKey: "taskName"))

    }

} catch {

    print("Failed")
}
```

with this

```
do {
    let result = try context.fetch(request)
    for data in result as! [Tasks] {
        print(data.value(forKey: "taskName"))
        if let reminders = data.value(forKey: "taskName") as? [Reminder] {
            for reminder in reminders {
                // Now you have your single object Reminder and you can print his variables
                print("Your reminder description is \(reminder. reminderDescription), and his length is \(reminder. reminderLength))"
            }
        }
    }

} catch {

    print("Failed")
}
```

Comment: I've mucked around with the core data but I'm just came to some more problems. I believe the data is saving and fetching, but now that I have tried to add a value to the array so it can actually save something that isn't just an empty array, it crashes, please refer to my edit. Thanks, Sav.

Comment: let newTask = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

First of all you should use your object "Reminder" instead NSManagedObject, and after that you should modify your object "Reminder" into a codable, can i see how you create your database .xcdatamodeld ?

Comment: @FrancescoDestino I have edited again, showing the data model. How do I go about changing the Reminder object into a codable?

Comment: @FrancescoDestino I believe that has worked but now I'm just getting a crash from the unwrapped optional as xcode wouldn't accept the ?, only the !. I believe this is because there is no values set in the array to begin with.

Comment: I've been trying for the past 30 minutes to fix: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, I haven't been able to correct this. What would you suggest? Thank you.

Comment: Update: I have corrected the forced unwrapping but I cant seem to save anything into the array because when I dump(reminderList) the next time I open the app, it is empty again. I'm close to starting from scratch as nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Can i see how you implemented the Object Tasks and how you fixed code in your viewDidLoad function?

Comment: I'm getting a lot of this in the output, <Simple_Reminders.Reminder: 0x60400046da00>,
<Simple_Reminders.Reminder: 0x60400046da40>,
<Simple_Reminders.Reminder: 0x60400046da80>,
<Simple_Reminders.Reminder: 0x60400046dac0>,
<Simple_Reminders.Reminder: 0x60400046db00>, 
but no actual reminder information or anything. I think this is built up saved data over time. I'll show you the code in my viewDidLoad, refer to the edit.

Comment: Thanks for that, makes a lot more sense. Still not receiving any values, just things like;
Optional(<__NSArray0 0x6000000184e0>(

)
)
Optional(<_TtGCs23_ContiguousArrayStorageC16Simple_Reminders8Reminder_ 0x6040002459a0>(
<Simple_Reminders.Reminder: 0x6040002688c0>
)

Comment: Oh yeah, now i understood the problem and how you create Objects and other stuff! Whatever, this print "Optional(<__NSArray0 0x6000000184e0>( ) )"  means that are you trying to print a complex object and not a simple one like a String or an Int, so you should probably do another for cicle to print every content in your array! I advice you to clear the database right now, so you can start from zero and watch clearly the problem you had :) but i will edit one more time my answer to help you print all reminder Strings :)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, it's working now. I can scroll through the output and read all of the attempts, it's pretty funny. Just how would I go about clearing the database? I've looked it up and context.delete(forkey: taskName) doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: That's how you clear an entity from the database
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Tasks")
        let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
        
        do {
            try context.persistentStoreCoordinator?.execute(deleteRequest, with: self.context)
        } catch {
            
        }


But remember that this command will delete every entity of type Tasks in your database, for other kind of stuff i recommend you to look some documentation ;)